# today I can't open markdown file on markdown viewer chrome extension

Tags: markdown

Today I've got error like this.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoJ2B.jpg)

Comment: You can report the error to the extension author.

Comment: my friend laptop . It works fine.

Comment: The error message is about a local file:// URL so I guess it is causing the difference. Also make sure you've allowed file access on `chrome://extensions` card's details page for that extension.

Comment: I uploaded my markdown file to my hosting web. then I opened it with chrome extension again . It works!!. that means the problem is local file.

Comment: I've turned on the Allow access to file URLs. for opening local file. before today there wasn't problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can fixed this problem by accessing local data files chrome use this command.

open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --allow-file-access-from-files

Comment: Please let me know how you solved it in more detail. I don't understand at all what you wrote. I have the same problem.

Comment: close chrome window and then open terminal use this command. for mac

Answer (score 2):

I just enabled the **Allow access to file URLs**, and it worked for me :)

[image]

Comment: Google Chrome - Version 112.0.5615.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

If you use old version Chrome, then markdown is working fine. It means latest Chrome has the problem with Markdown. Now, I'm using two versions. You have to enable "Allow access to file URLs".

For now we can use this portable version of Chrome (v79): 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Google%20Chrome%20Portable/GoogleChromePortable64_79.0.3945.130_online.paf.exe/download
for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Something in Chrome's "Enhanced protection" level of "Safe Browsing" prevents the Markdown Viewer extension from doing the right thing, even if you've enabled it in all the usual ways.

Workaround:  In Chrome's settings, select "Privacy and security", drill down to "Safe Browsing" and switch from "Enhanced protection" to "Standard protection".